# Does SSO login works with Data Loader CLI?

Tags: data-loader, single-sign-on, commandline

For security reasons we are establishing SSO login to the entire org but we are facing an issue coming to Data loader CLI users. In CLI the username and password are provided in the process-conf files, how can SSO be enabled and used for the Data Loader CLI users without providing the Username and password in the conf files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @identigral It's informative on Dataloader GUI. I'm looking for Data Loader CLI, It would be nice to know how to use SSO for CLI